# Finding a way to properly implement <main> tag in this layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, semantic-markup

I'm laying out HTML for a project, and as you can see on the joined picture, I have an issue about properly implementing `<main>` tag.

My layout has a content header above the sidebar and content, which prevents me from keeping the sidebar outside the `main` tag.

Would someone have a solution?

[image]

I tried having the sidebar code below the content in the HTML structure, and display it as shown in the picture with flexbox reverse row, but as soon as I wrap what I want inside a `<main>` semantic tag, everything breaks.

Comment: Please show your attempt as code. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Further to Heretic Monkey's suggestion, at the *very least* post your [mcve] code in your question.

Comment: This is a (well defined, narrowly focused) "How To" question, not a debugging question.

Comment: Is there a *reason* that there *needs* to be a `main` tag? You could do the whole thing with a single wrapper in CSS-Grid? We shouldn't add elements purely for the sake of "semantics"...the web really doesn't care. We should make sure that **if** elements are used they are semantic....not the other way round.

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, i'm just dumbly following best practices and was surprised this case figure -which seems quite basic- was causing frictions. At that point i'm just asking here for expertise helping me resolve that case. If there is no solution i'll just drop the main tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: contents;` to stop the `main` element having any effect on layout. Then layout its children as if they were siblings of `main` instead of children of it.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "content-header content-header content-header" "sidebar content content";
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background: #aaf;
  grid-area: header;
}

main {
  display: contents;
}

main header {
  background: #faa;
  grid-area: content-header;
}

main #content {
  background: #afa;
  grid-area: content;
}

aside {
  background: #aff;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>
  <header>
    content header
  </header>
  <div id="content">
    content
  </div>
</main>
<aside>
  sidebar
</aside>
```

Comment: 'Ware support for `display:contents` though.

Comment: Thanks Quentin for the solution and @Paulie_D for the warning, i'll try to make my mind about this!